# javascript function that accepts (#id).val() returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with the id="kill".

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$("#kill").click(function(){ 
    getImage($(this).val()); 
});

function getImage(code){  
    var code, 
        imgstr;
    imgstr="mypath/"+code+".png";  
    return imgstr;
}
```

Unfortunately, the wrong value is getting returned. But if I assign the value inside the function getImage, like this:

```
$("#kill").click(function(){ 
    getImage($(this).val()); 
});

function getImage(code){  
    var code="12", 
        imgstr;
    imgstr="mypath/"+code+".png";  
    return imgstr;
}
```

Then it returns the correct value.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you hide you `code` parameter with a variable of the same name? 
Do you rely on `code` for your `imgstr` calculation? Then you are not using the correct `code`.

Comment: Your code actually seems to work the way you want it to. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bg2nj/

Comment: And what is the wrong value that you get in the first version? It works perfectly well with me: http://jsfiddle.net/FLbn9/ so the problem must be elsewhere. Are you sure you don't have duplicate ids? If you have more than one element with the id `kill` it won't work correctly.

Comment: @Jerone M Altura: `the returned value is wrong` is not really informative... what does it return? Also you should post your HTML, as we don't know what `kill` is...

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the value use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function and instead of:

```
getImage($(this.val));
```

you should use:

```
getImage($(this).val());
```

Comment: i have done this
getImage($(this.val()));
but still returns a wrong value;

Comment: Nope, `getImage($(this).val());`.

Answer (score 0):

Why creating another local variable with same name ? (May be this is overwriting the passed `code`, in some browser.)

Use this,

```
$("#kill").click(function(){ 
    getImage($(this).val()); 
});

function getImage(code){  
    var localCode = code,
    imgstr;
    imgstr="mypath/"+localCode+".png";  
    return imgstr;
}
```

Comment: I thought that at first, but it shouldn't matter.  An empty var declaration is one of the recommended methods of "importing" a global variable to the current scope.  I couldn't find a browser that overwrote as suspected.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. I did know that this is the recommended method. Any links for reference ?

Answer (score 0):

From above all discussion I can say that you are using older version of jQuery(maybe < than 1.6). Check version of jQuery if version is < 1.6 than for button use `.attr("value")` instead of `.val()`, may be this(not tested) works!!

```
$("#kill").click(function(){ 
    getImage($(this).attr("value")); 
});

function getImage(code){  
    var code, 
        imgstr;
    imgstr="mypath/"+code+".png";  
    return imgstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the local 'code' variable. It is hiding the parameter.